# Is that possible to generate a list of maps from myBatis

Tags: mybatis

for example, I have queries `select id, name, age, address from staffs`, instead of having a list of Staff object. I'd prefer to have a list of maps, as

```
list{
  map{
    ("id", 123),
    ("name","jackie"),
    ("address", "canada"),
    ("age",26)
  }
  map{
    ("id", 126),
    ("name","james"),
    ("address", "canada"),
    ("age",27)
  }

}
```

is that possible, and how to do that, if possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is possible. You can set `resultType` as `Hashmap` in your mapper xml file, and it will return a list of maps.

```
<select id="selectFromStaffs" resultType="Hashmap">
    select id, name, age, address from staffs
</select>
```

And you get it the same way:

```
...
List listOfMaps = sqlSession.selectList("selectFromStaffs");
...
```

You can read more about it in the [User Guide](http://mybatis.googlecode.com/files/MyBatis-3-User-Guide.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

In mapper xml type `resultType` as `"map"` or `"Hashmap"`, mapper interface you must write reutrn type as a `"List"`:

StaffMapper.xml

```
<select id="getStaffList" resultType="map">
    select id, name, age, address from staffs
</select>
```

StaffMapper.java

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
public interface StaffMapper {
    List<Map<String, Object>> getStaffList();//List getStaffList();
}
```