# Generate a list of maps from myBatis with null values

Tags: mybatis

my question is very related with this other [Is that possible to generate a list of maps from myBatis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344263/is-that-possible-to-generate-a-list-of-maps-from-mybatis),
but i find a problem when a column has null value.

I have this query:

```
<select id="executeQuery"  resultType="map">
select name,age from customer</select>
```

I woud like this result:

```
list{
  map{
    ("name","john"),
    ("age",33)
  }
  map{
    ("name","james"),
    ("age",)
  }
}
```

But like age in the second one is null, i am having this:

```
list{
  map{
    ("name","john"),
    ("age",33)
  }
  map{
    ("name","james"),
  }
}
```

It is posible directly with mybatis?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871449/mybatis-null-value-for-resultype-hashmap

Comment: Thank you, I have searched but not found this one.